# Email notfications from burrow

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there anyway i can configure burrow to send email notifications when the lag=0 in the kafka queue. this is my config.

```
[general]
logdir=log
logconfig=config/logging.cfg
pidfile=burrow.pid
client-id=burrow-lagchecker
group-blacklist=^(console-consumer-|python-kafka-consumer-).*$
 #group-whitelist=^(my-important-consumer).*$

[zookeeper]
hostname=zkhost01.example.com
hostname=zkhost02.example.com
hostname=zkhost03.example.com
port=2181
timeout=6
lock-path=/burrow/notifier

[kafka "local"]
broker=kafka01.example.com
broker=kafka02.example.com
broker=kafka03.example.com
broker=kafka04.example.com
broker=kafka05.example.com
broker-port=10251
zookeeper=zkhost01.example.com
zookeeper=zkhost02.example.com
zookeeper=zkhost03.example.com
zookeeper-port=2181
zookeeper-path=/kafka-cluster
offsets-topic=__consumer_offsets

[storm "local"]
zookeeper=zkhost01.example.com
zookeeper=zkhost02.example.com
zookeeper=zkhost03.example.com
zookeeper-port=2181
zookeeper-path=/kafka-cluster/stormconsumers

 [tickers]
 broker-offsets=60

  [lagcheck]
  intervals=10
  expire-group=604800


 [smtp]
 server=mailserver.example.com
 port=25
 from=burrow-noreply@example.com
 template=config/default-email.tmpl

 [emailnotifier "xxh@example.com"]
 group=local,critical-consumer-group
 group=local,other-consumer-group
 interval=60

 [notify]
 interval=10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add threshold variable to your configuration

```
[notifier.gemail]
class-name="email"
interval=30
threshold=1
```

https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/wiki/Notifier-Email
https://godoc.org/github.com/linkedin/Burrow/core/protocol#StatusConstant